# How to create different windows on Java GUI?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, game-development

So I have created a game and I'm just finishing up the project now but then at then end  I realised I need to have a home screen where the player has the option to press start button or settings. My initial plan was to create another class with a new home screen frame called frame. In this class I implemented ActionListener interface and created a start button. If start button is pressed then hide or dispose and creat a new instance of GamePanel. Then in GamePanel's ActionListener I said if menu button is pressed then dispose and create new instance of screen.

Everything worked as planned but then again I realised that the icon for JFrame is blinking like a christmas light in my taskbar. When I press start in the home screen frame then JFrame is disposed so it disappears from the taskbar then instantly appears again since another frame is opened (this is very annoying). I'm here to ask you guys if there is another easy way since I am out of time at this moment? I tried using different JPanels but lets just say it got too complicated.

````java
public class Screen extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    HScreen() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(startButton);
        startButton.setBounds(250, 90, 100, 50);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == startButton) {
            frame.dispose();
            new GamePanel();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HScreen();
    }

}```
````

Comment: Show your window management code, maybe?

Comment: The ActioLlistener method?

Comment: A "home screen" suggests a `CardLayout`

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be changing jframes, but changing the components within the jframe. If you want multiple windows you should have a JDialog. A card layout lets you "switch screens". When your game is opened one JPanel would be displayed, you click start, then another JPanel is displayed, then the game ends, ...guess what another JPanel is displayed.

Comment: I'm assuming `HScreen()` is supposed to be `public Screen()`. Anyway, you configure `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`, but in the start button handler you have `frame.dispose();`, which should trigger the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` operation to call `System exit()` and exit your application. Even if this isn't the cause of your problem, it's probably not what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you're running some kind of thread/timer which is constantly requesting keyboard focus for your game window, which suggests you're using a `KeyListener`. You could fix the immediate issue (of the task bar buttons flashing) by using the Key Bindings API instead (of `KeyListener`, which should just do).  Another choice is to use a `WindowFocusListener` and pause/resume you "game loop" when focus is lost/gained.  But in this context, I would just make use of a `CardLayout`.  You could also make use of an `OverlayLayout` or `JLayeredPane` if you want to "overlay" on top of the game

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new JFrame instance for each screen, you can consider using a CardLayout to switch between different JPanels. A CardLayout allows you to stack multiple JPanels on top of each other, and switch between them using a card name or index.